# How to always use withTrashed() for model Binding

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

In my app, I use soft delete on a lot of object, but I still want to access them in my app, just showing a special message that this item has been deleted and give the opportunity to restore it.

Currently I have to do this for all my route parametters in my RouteServiceProvider:

```php
    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {


        parent::boot();

        Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
            return User::withTrashed()->find($value);
        });

        Route::bind('post', function ($value) {
            return Post::withTrashed()->find($value);
        });

        [...]


    }
```

Is there a quicker and better way to add the trashed Object to the model binding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For Laravel 5.6 to 7

You can follow this doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout#soft-deleting. And set the `soft_delete` option of the `config/scout.php` configuration file to `true`.

```
'soft_delete' => true,
```

## For Laravel 8+

You can follow this doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-soft-deleted-models. And append `->withTrashed()` to the route that should accept trashed models:

Ex:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', function (User $user) {
    return $user->email;
})->withTrashed();
```

Answer (score 5):

Jerodev's answer didn't work for me. The `SoftDeletingScope` continued to filter out the deleted items. So I just overrode that scope and the `SoftDeletes` trait:

**SoftDeletingWithDeletesScope.php:**

```
namespace App\Models\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

class SoftDeletingWithDeletesScope extends SoftDeletingScope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
    }
}
```

**SoftDeletesWithDeleted.php:**

```
namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Models\Scopes\SoftDeletingWithDeletesScope;

trait SoftDeletesWithDeleted
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public static function bootSoftDeletes()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new SoftDeletingWithDeletesScope);
    }
}
```

This effectively just removes the filter while still allowing me to use all the rest of the `SoftDeletingScope` extensions.

Then in my model I replaced the `SoftDeletes` trait with my new `SoftDeletesWithDeleted` trait:

```
use App\Models\Traits\SoftDeletesWithDeleted;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletesWithDeleted;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes) to the models that have to be visible even when trashed.

For example:

```
class WithTrashedScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->withTrashed();
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new WithTrashedScope);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
If you don't want to show the deleted objects you can still manually add `->whereNull('deleted_at')` to your query.

Comment: It would make the soft deleted irrelevant, I could just remove the softDelete Trait but then, my soft deleted object would always be shawn.

For Example, I want to display a list of all my active users, or do an autocomplete on them and I don't want soft deleted to show.

I only want them in the model Binding so I don't get a 404 when doing a request on them