# Laravel Model binding including SoftDeleted values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a `Route::resource('sheeps', 'SheepsController')` with a show function returning a resource:

```php
public function show(Sheep $sheep)
{
    return new SheepResource(
        $sheep->load('farm')
    );
}
```

So when I call `/api/sheeps/123` should I get Sheep `123`, but... I don't get it, because it's *softdeleted*.
How to fix the resource that it also searches in softdeleted results?

Comment: unfortunately implicit model binding has its limitations ... as others will/have pointed out, you will probably have to wonder into `explicit model binding` to take care of this, so you can customize the resolution logic of that binding (add the `withTrashed`)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this :

in your  RouteServiceProvider :

```php
/**     
* Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
*
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{


    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('sheep', function ($value) {
        return Sheep::withTrashed()->find($value);
    });



}
```

Comment: So far, that's the best way I found, you can also disable the softDelete Scope in your model, but in my opinion, it made the whole softDelete things irrelevant.

Actually,, I have an open Question in SO here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749901/how-to-always-use-withtrashed-for-model-binding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $sheep = Sheep::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
```

and update your route
or

```
public function show(int $sheep)
{
    $sheep = Sheep::withTrashed()->findOrFail($sheep);
```

or 
use [Explicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#explicit-binding)